# How to request data when application is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, request, send

Is it possible to send API request even if the app is not working on the background. FourSquare can send push notifications while the app is not working if there's a friend nearby. So I thought it's technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** run code when the app has been killed*.
But you can send Push notifications from your server even if the app is killed. That's what Foursquare does, based on your last location update.

**Edit:**
*by the user

Comment: I don't think (im not sure) if FourSquare uses the last location update. Because it always uses the location even if the app is killed, and when you change location, and go to place which is close to a friend, it sends push notification. It must send your location to the API to know that you're close to someone.

Comment: If you manually kill the app, Foursquare will not receive new location updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Background Fetch` also and override

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

//Make request code and compare the response below

 if(olddata){
 completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
 NSLog(@"No new data found.");
 }
else{
 //Local Notification
 completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
 NSLog(@"Fetch completed");
}

}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

return YES;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: u can also refer this nice tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

Comment: It won't work if the app has been killed by the user.

Comment: yup,the app must be in background or if killed by OS not by user

Comment: I think it's about working on BackGround, not after the app is killed.

Comment: it will not work i told u.if u manually kill the app.But if system kills it den it will wokr